# How to connect Share point for app only via clientid & client secret to get the access token on azure Using JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot, sharepoint

I am able to find the corresponding .net method in Token helper class with GetAppOnlyAccessToken and it has CreateAccessTokenRequestWithClientCredentials method used to get access token via client id and client secret. 
But there is no method found on java side where without user credentials and only with client id and secret i can get access token of share point.
Please help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of below libraries:

- [azure-activedirectory-library-for-java](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java)
- [microsoft-authentication-library-for-java](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java)(recommended)

Below is a demo about how to get token for sharepoint via clientid/client secret:

```
IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
    ConfidentialClientApplication cca =
            ConfidentialClientApplication
                    .builder(CLIENT_ID, credential)
                    .authority(AUTHORITY)
                    .setTokenCacheAccessAspect(tokenCacheAspect)
                    .build();

        ClientCredentialParameters parameters =
                    ClientCredentialParameters
                            .builder(SCOPE)
                            .build();

        result = cca.acquireToken(parameters).join();
```

The scope should be sharepoint resource, not ms graph.

```
scope = new string[] { "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/.default" };
```

For more details, please refer to:

- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/dev/src/samples/confidential-client/ClientCredentialGrant.java

BR